# React functional component, useState call back without using useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state, asynccallback

I'm pretty new to reactJS, and may have either over complicated things or didn't plan it properly.

I have encountered an issue with using the useState hook to keep track of properties in my project.

ok, so here goes

1. `value` is taken from an input text box as type text, due to using `react-hook-form`
2. `type` is then checked, to see if it's equal to "Income" or "Expense"
3. If `type == "income"` then just set the `value` using `setValue` without any changes, else if `type == "expense"` then `*=-1` and set `value` using `setValue`
4. `parseInt()` is used with the `setValue` to make sure the value is saved as a number
5. `setRecords` is called to add the relevant information into `record` array of objects.

so as you can see from the 5 steps above, useState hook `setValue` and `setRecords` is getting called one after the other, the issue I'm having at the moment is that on the initial run of the app, the `value` would append instead of adding.

from what I understand is that because the useState hook is asynchronous and does not return a result immediately, so by the time the `setRecords` is called, `value` still of type text instead of number

I have been searching online for a while but was unable to find a good way to resolve this issue, without using useEffect hook, I have tried to use useEffect hook, but I didn't manage to get it to work, the user is allowed to enter the same `value` and the app should still append the value into the `record` array of objects.

in the end, I decided to create a new property `currentValue` and set it on form submit, because this is not a state and will update immediately, it won't have to wait for `setValue` to update the `value` state.

Is there a better way to work around this issue? or is the workaround ok?

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import RecordList from "./RecordList";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { BudgetPlannerContext } from "../context/BudgetPlannerContext";

const BudgetPlanner = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const [
    records,
    setRecords,
    total,
    setTotal,
    type,
    setType,
    value,
    setValue,
    description,
    setDescription,
  ] = useContext(BudgetPlannerContext);

  let currentValue = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    setTotal(() =>
      records.reduce((acc, curr) => {
        return acc + curr.value;
      }, 0)
    );
  }, [records, setTotal]);

  const onFormSubmit = (data) => {
    if ((type === "Income") & (data.value !== 0)) {
      currentValue = parseInt(data.value);
      setValue(parseInt(data.value));
    } else if ((type === "Expense") & (data.value !== 0)) {
      currentValue = parseInt((data.value *= -1));
      setValue(parseInt((data.value *= -1)));
    } else {
      return null;
    }
    setDescription(data.description);
    processValue(type, currentValue);
  };

  const processValue = (type, currentValue) => {
    updateRecord(type, currentValue);
    //setValue(0);
    //setDescription("");
    //console.log(records);
  };

  const updateRecord = (type, currentValue) => {
    setRecords((oldRecord) => [
      ...oldRecord,
      {
        type: type,
        value: currentValue,
        description: description,
        id: Math.random() * 1000,
      },
    ]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="ui segment">
      <div className="search-bar ui segment">
        <form className="ui form" onSubmit={handleSubmit(onFormSubmit)}>
          <div className="field">
            <select
              onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.value)}
              name="todos"
              ref={register}
              className="filter-todo"
            >
              <option value="" defaultValue="defaultValue">
                ---
              </option>
              <option value="Income">Income</option>
              <option value="Expense">Expense</option>
            </select>
            <input
              name="description"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Description"
              ref={register}
            />
            <input
              name="value"
              type="number"
              placeholder="Value"
              ref={register}
            />
          </div>
          <div>Total: {total}</div>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <RecordList records={records} setRecords={setRecords} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BudgetPlanner;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd just pass the new value as a parameter to the other functions you're calling:

```
const onFormSubmit = (data) => {
    if (data.value === 0 || (type !== 'Income' && type !== 'Expense')) {
        return;
    }
    const newValue = parseInt(data.value) * (type === 'Income' ? 1 : -1);
    setValue(newValue);
    setDescription(data.description);
    processValue(type, newValue);
};
```

No need for an extra outer variable.

Another option is to use `useEffect` (or, preferably, `useLayoutEffect`) and call `processValue` when `value` changes:

```
const onFormSubmit = (data) => {
    if (data.value === 0 || (type !== 'Income' && type !== 'Expense')) {
        return;
    }
    const newValue = parseInt(data.value) * (type === 'Income' ? 1 : -1);
    setValue(newValue);
    setDescription(data.description);
};
useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (value) {
        processValue(type);
    }
}, [value]);
```

and have `processValue` use the outer `value` stateful variable.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I have taken your first suggestion on the `onFormSubmit` function and made changes to my code, now it looks much better.